# RSA Sign: OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to code with EVP interface of Openssl for RSA signing with SHA1. Later I would like to expand signing with different digest algorithms and different signature algorithms(sor of generic, and therefore the use of EVP).

I seem to get a segmentation fault whenever I try to retrieve the size of my private key

Can someone tell me how to correct this?

```
int rsaSign(char *in_file, char * sig_file){

        char *data = NULL;
        int data_len;
        unsigned int sig_len;
        unsigned char *sig;
        int err = -1;

        OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
        FILE *fd;
        EVP_PKEY *priv_key = EVP_PKEY_new();
        RSA *privkey = NULL;
           printf( "we are here..\n");

        if ((fd = fopen(PRIVKEY_FILE, "r")) == NULL){
            printf("error reading file\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        privkey = RSA_new();
        if (!PEM_read_PrivateKey(fd, &privkey, NULL, NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA Private Key File.\n");
            return 2;
        }

        fclose(fd);

        if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA (priv_key, privkey))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA: failed.\n");
            return 3;
        }

        if (!priv_key) {
            printf("no private key\n");
        }
        EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(privkey, priv_key);


        EVP_MD_CTX *ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

        const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");

        if (!md) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating message digest");
            fprintf(stderr, " object, unknown name?\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            exit(1);
        }



        if (!EVP_SignInit(ctx, md))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignInit: failed.\n");
                EVP_PKEY_free(priv_key);
                return 3;
            }
        printf( "now to sign update..\n");
        data = readFile(in_file);
        data_len = strlen(data);
        printf("data len = %d\n", data_len);

        if (!EVP_SignUpdate(ctx, data, data_len))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignUpdate: failed.\n");
            EVP_PKEY_free(priv_key);
            return 3;
        }
        printf( "now to sign final..\n");

sig = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(privkey)); //!!!!! SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE !!!!!


        if (!EVP_SignFinal(ctx, &sig, &sig_len, priv_key))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignFinal: failed.\n");
            free(sig);
            EVP_PKEY_free(priv_key);
            return 3;
        }

        free(data);
        free(sig);
        EVP_PKEY_free(priv_key);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Can you add the size returning from EVP_PKEY_size()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several problems:

- `PEM_read_PrivateKey()` expects an `EVP_PKEY **`, not an `RSA **` - in fact, you do not need an `RSA *` object at all;
- You should not be calling `EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA()`;
- You should not be calling `EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA()`.

To load the private key, you can simply do:

```
EVP_PKEY *priv_key = NULL;

if (!PEM_read_PrivateKey(rsa_pkey_file, &priv_key, NULL, NULL))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error loading Private Key File.\n");
    return 2;
}
```

You may now call `EVP_PKEY_size(priv_key)` to determine the key size.

Additionally, your `EVP_SignFinal()` call is wrong - you should be passing `sig`, not `&sig`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm no expert in that particular library, but having perused the API docs, I think this:

```
EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(privkey, priv_key);
```

should be:

```
EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(priv_key, privkey);
```

and similarly shouldn't the line you've highlighted as SEGFAULTing refer to `priv_key` not `privkey` also:

```
sig = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(priv_key));
```

Both these mistakes would be easier to see if you change your variable names to something easier to distinguish (rather than `privkey` and `priv_key`, use `priv_key_RSA` and `priv_key_EVP`

Having variables which differ only in their underscores is a *really* bad idea :)